# Html.TextBoxFor not submitting a value using HttpPost to controller

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-3

This is a simple issue and something I've done before but I can't see why this isn't working.

Here's my HTML helper:

```
<%= Html.TextBoxFor(am => Model.Amount, new { @id = "myAmount" })%>
```

I submit the form from the same view using a submit button:

```
<input id="myprocess" type="submit" value="Submit" name="myprocess">
```

And it hits my controller when I debug:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ProcessCreate(myModel m)
{..code here..}
```

But my model property 'm.Amount' is set to the default zero.  I know this is obvious but I don't see why this isn't working.

Comment: Is `Amount` a property (i.e. have public getters and setters)?

Comment: Yes, it is an automatic property.

Comment: Other possible causes are you have disabled it (any javascript?), you have another input for the same property (a hidden input?) or its not inside the form tags You should use your browser tools to check what is being posted, and server side, check `Request.Form` to see whats being received.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your responses.  I found what the problem was. There was some jquery which used a maskMoney function which changed the type from decimal to string.  My model type for 'Amount' was decimal which had the default value 0.  So I changed the type to string, passed it to my controller and parsed it back to a decimal type.

Answer (score 1):

Does your BeginForm call (or your `<form>`) wrap the textbox?

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("ProcessCreate", "ControllerName", FormMethod.Post)) %>
<% { %>
    ....
    <%= Html.TextBoxFor(am => Model.Amount, new { @id = "myAmount" })%>
    ....
<% } %>
```

(This may be the wrong syntax, I haven't worked in MVC2 in a while).

Answer (score 0):

The lambda expression is incorrect. You need to change it to:

```
<%= Html.TextBoxFor(am => am.Amount, new { @id = "myAmount" })%>
```